# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when trying to install Lombok

Tags: java, macos, java-8, lombok, failed-installation

I am trying to install Lombok but I am getting the below error.
I am using a MacOS HighSierra and I'ver tried different versions of Lombok.

Help me, please!

**java -jar lombok-1.16.18.jar**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/Cellar/adoptopenjdk-openjdk8/jdk8u172-b11/jre/lib/libfontmanager.dylib: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/adoptopenjdk-openjdk8/jdk8u172-b11/jre/lib/libfontmanager.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/adoptopenjdk-openjdk8/jdk8u172-b11/jre/lib/libfontmanager.dylib
  Reason: image not found
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1845)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit$1.run(LWCToolkit.java:93)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit$1.run(LWCToolkit.java:80)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit.<clinit>(LWCToolkit.java:79)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1736)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(EventQueue.java:1294)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(SwingUtilities.java:1295)
    at lombok.installer.Installer.guiInstaller(Installer.java:164)
    at lombok.installer.Installer.access$000(Installer.java:58)
    at lombok.installer.Installer$GraphicalInstallerApp.runApp(Installer.java:123)
    at lombok.core.Main.go(Main.java:128)
    at lombok.core.Main.main(Main.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at lombok.launch.Main.main(Main.java:36)
```

Comment: which IDE are you using for java development? If you use IntelliJ, you just need to use lombok maven dependency in pom.xml.

Comment: And of course: what version of java (jdk) do you have installed on your mac?

Comment: I am using java 8. It turns out that the installation works if I click the jar file directly and select the IDE. Thanks!